# Use string from page in ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a site that makes an AJAX call for data and then writes the HTML to the page to display it. I would like to build the functionality to be able to click a button, get a string from an element with that id, and then use it in another AJAX call. Is this possible?

This is part of the initial call.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
        data: {
            api_key:"69abb9ae8bc1af849baf2a2890e08d08",
            name: artistSearch,
            limit: 1,

        },
        url: "http://api.musicgraph.com/api/v2/artist/search",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.data[0].name);
            var myHTML = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                myHTML += '<li class="artistName  list-group-item">';
                myHTML += '<span class="name" id="artist_name">' + data.data[0].name + '</span></br>';
                myHTML += '<span class="country">Country of Origin: ' + data.data[0].country_of_origin + '</span></br>';
                myHTML += '<span class="country">Decade: ' + data.data[0].decade + '</span></br>';
                myHTML += '<span class="country">Genre of Music: ' + data.data[0].main_genre + '</span></br>';


            }
```

I would like to take the id #artist_name from the page after it is loaded, and on a button click, grab that value to use in another ajax call. How would this be done?

Comment: `after the page is loaded` is this a form submit or redirect?

Comment: You're using the same `id="artist_name"` every time through the loop. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Wait a second, you're just looping 1 time. Why do you have a loop at all?

Comment: If there's just one `#artist_name`, use `$("#artist_name").text()` to grab the name from it when processing the button click.

Comment: @Barmar I have not fully implemented it yet in this code but the purpose of the loop is to make run through a get albums for each artist, then when requested, get a track list for those albums for example.

Comment: Then you can't use `id="artist_name"` every time, because IDs have to be unique. When they click the button, how will it know which artist name to send in the second AJAX request?

Comment: @Barmar I realized as I was working further on it. I don't think it is possible to do what I was trying to do. Thanks anyway.